# Understanding notation for partial derivatives of implicit functions where arguments are given as expressions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem 8 of section 12.8 "Adams - Calculus - A complete course 8th ed" is as follows:
*Calculate the indicated derivative. Assume function F has continuous first partial derivatives*
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \ \ \ \ \ \ F(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)=0$$
The notation $F_k$ for the partial derivative of $F$ w.r.t. the $k$'th variable is convenient in finding a solution to this problem.
We assume that $z=z(x,y)$ and hence $\partial y / \partial x = 0$ (i.e. $x$ and $y$ are independent variables).
So, we differentiate $F$ implicitly w.r.t. $x$;
$$ F_1(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)\left(2x-2z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+ F_2(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)\left(2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + z + x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)=0$$
We get our answer solving for $\partial z/\partial x$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{2xF_1(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)+zF_2(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)}{2zF_1(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)-xF_2(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)}$$
The problem now is how to intepret the notation in applications. Normally, we have functions of the form $F(x,y)$ and the partial derivative $F_1$ is the same as $F_x$, but is this valid here ?

If we were to use this expression to find a numerical answer for $\partial z/\partial x$ for some function $F(x^2-z^2, y^2+xz)=F(u,v)=0$, at some (valid) point $(x,y,z)$ where $u=x^2-z^2, \ v=y^2+xz$, then could we calculate this as
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{2xF_u(u,v) + zF_v(u,v)}{2zF_u(u,v) - xF_v(u,v)}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the answer depend on dz/dy ?

Comment: The solution to the problem is $\partial z/\partial x$, where $z=z(x,y)$, i.e. $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, so the answer would not depend on $\partial z/\partial y$.

Comment: You are right. I did not realize that there are two equations (i.e., $F_1 = F_2 = 0$) for two unknowns (i.e., $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x},  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$)